# output rspec tests on screen while redirecting them to a file

Tags: ruby, rspec-puppet

In .rpsec, 

`--format json
--out rspec.json`

This setting redirects rspec tests results to rspec.json.

At same time I also want to watch these results displaying on screen .  Is there a way doing that?

Answer (score 2):

RSpec supports [multiple formatters](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/command-line/format-option#multiple-formats) in a command. So for instance, I can setup my **.rspec** file to look like:

```
--format json
--out rspec.json
--format progress
```

and when I run `rake spec`, I see the default progress indicators in the terminal and a **rspec.json** file is created with the JSON output.